# How to create a custom field on Case Comment object?

Tags: case

We want to add time field so that our representatives will add the time spent when adding the case comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently add custom fields to case comments directly. [Go vote on that idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YHGTAA4). However, some alternatives could include building a custom Case Comments object that copies its values to the out-of-the-box object (minus the custom data, of course) by way of workflow, trigger, or process, or building a Visualforce page to capture the data separately (as suggested in one of the idea's comments).